# GPS Location - Do it on Device or on Server?

Tags: android, gps

This will be for an Android Application, but the idea itself can be applied to anything.

I want my app to find the location of the user, and then check to see if the user's location is on a set list of locations.

The list is currently stored on a web server, and is in the format of -

```
Suburb - Street
```

So I currently have the following options -

1. Have the Android Device get the GPS Location of the device, do a lookup to get the current Suburb and Street, and check it against the list on the server
2. Have the Android Device get the GPS Location of the device, do a lookup to get the current Suburb and Street, retrieve the list from the server, and check the list locally.
3. Have the Android Device get the GPS Location, send the location to the server, and the server does the lookup to get suburb and street to check against the list, and then send a response back.

Which would be the most efficient way of doing things, both in terms of maintenance, as well as bandwidth wise ?

Also, if there are other methods of achieving the same goal, I would be happy to be made aware of them !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as building a Distributed System of `3-tier Architecture`. it recommends that you let the `Application server` which is your `server` in your case. to handle the processing to reduce the Latency.

so the android application should be the `interface` only where the user uses to communicate with the server and all the processing should be handled in the server.

So for me I'd choose the third choice.

for more about 3-tier architecture please read [this](http://alitarhini.wordpress.com/2011/01/22/concepts-of-three-tier-architecture/)

hope this helped you answer your question. good luck with your application.

Comment: Thanks ! The third option was what seemed the most logical to me but I couldn't quite work out why. Thanks for the link too, time to get reading :)